# Ext JS SuperBoxSelect component

Tags: javascript, extjs

As you can see in the following screenshot, the SuperBoxSelect component can show multiple selected items on the same line e.g Conneticut and Florida

[image]

I would like to change this behavior so that each selection is shown on its own line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting stackItems property to true

stackItems When set to true, the items will be stacked 1 per line. Defaults to false which displays the items inline.

```
 stackItems: true
```